# Made horizontal responsive menu, li's overlap in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists, padding

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP0GT.jpg)! [internet explorer]

This css works in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, but it refuses to work even in the latest IE 11. The li's overlap, and it creates a space at the top of the list. If I get rid of the height on the li, the text no longer overlaps. Instead, I get humongous padding on each li that I can't get rid of unless I set a height.

Let me know if I should provide more information. Thank you.

Below is the li's

```
.dropdown-menu > li {
    padding-left: 15px;
    height:25px;
    zoom:1;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:14px;
}
*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.five-col{
    -moz-column-count:5;
    -webkit-column-count:5;
}
*********This is on the li > a
.dropdown-menu > li > a{
    display:block;
    padding:3px 20px;
    clear:both;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.428;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

********HTML is as follows
<div id="#category-list">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a>Main Link</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a>link</a></li>
                <li><a>link</a></li>
                <li><a>link</a></li>
                ... etc.
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this HORRIBLE bug by doing an ie hack (surprise surprise!).

THE FIX:
The inline-block hack.
display: inline-block only works on IE that naturally have display: inline; rule. When it is not the case, IE will treat the declared inline-block element. Then, in a separate rule, turn the element back into a block again.

The tutorial is here: 
http://www.kovioko.net/tutorial/extra-spacing-and-incorrect-height-on-list-items-in-internet-explorer

checkout the last solution called The inline-block hack and that is the solution that helped me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Visit below link, it will help you.

```
http://css3menu.com/neat-red.html#
```

Comment: The menu you suggested isn't responsive.

Comment: Tutorial for responsive menu
http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/responsive-menu-tutorial